# What is the behaviour of attitude indicator with a lower than standard gyro speed?

Tags: gyroscopic-instruments

How does attitude indicator behave if its gyro is spinning at lower revolutions per minute than its designed specification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a little bit of research on this.
A gyro spinning slower than normal will cause the attitude indicator to be sluggish to respond and slowly fall out of position. Worn-out bearings on the gyro mean it won't be able to spin as fast as it should to maintain the required RPMs to display a true attitude. The indicator's slow falling out or sluggish movement is known as precessing. The readings will slowly drift out of place.

sources - [https://www.mcico.com/resource-center/articles/attitude-indicator-error-erecting-mechanism#:~:text=Worn%20out%20bearings%20on%20the,there%20is%20too%20much%20friction](https://www.mcico.com/resource-center/articles/attitude-indicator-error-erecting-mechanism#:%7E:text=Worn%20out%20bearings%20on%20the,there%20is%20too%20much%20friction).

Comment: But, there *is* a mechanism to compensate for precession, so-- if you were flying straight and level, would it really fall out of position?

Comment: how much can it compensate... there will come a point where it'll fall out

Comment: Please share the research itself, linking to an authoritative source that supports your conclusion. As it stands, your answer amounts to "somebody on the internet claims that..." without any real support, and for somebody disinclined toward the presented conclusion, that's not really a credible answer.

Comment: @RalphJ  thanks for the advice, will follow in the future, have edited my answer.